# I want to delete a particular line in the docx if it has a particular word using poi xwpf

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to delete a particular line in the docx if it has a particular word, say "killer".  How i can write a program using poi xwpf? If i replace it with empty data, the line will be still there.

Actually I am able to find the particular text in the docx file so that i can match and decide whether to delete that particular line using the below code:

```
for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> xwpfRuns = xwpfParagraph.getRuns();
        for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : xwpfRuns) {
            String xwpfRunText = xwpfRun.getText(xwpfRun
                    .getTextPosition());
            System.out.println(xwpfRunText);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : replcementMap
                    .entrySet()) {
                if (xwpfRunText != null
                        && xwpfRunText.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                    xwpfRunText = xwpfRunText.replaceAll(
                            entry.getKey() , entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            xwpfRun.setText(xwpfRunText, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted to substitute text in doc file.
Here is brilliant example:
http://moodygeeky.wordpress.com/
Just import the 2 class:

```
There are 2 classes:
```

**ZipUtility – to handle zipping and unzipping of files**
**SubstituteText – for substituting of text in .docx files**

And replace these strings as your preferences :

```
// Names of placeholders, starting and ending with % (to be updated
    // accordingly)
    String placeholder1 = "%name%";
    String placeholder2 = "%text%";

    // Values to replace placeholders (to be updated accordingly)
    String var1 = escapeHTML("newName"); // %name%
    String var2 = escapeHTML("newText"); // %text%
```